# Why doesn't this disable button in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to disable one of my buttons when clicked until a test is done. I've had a working disable before, but it was only cosmetic since the button still could be pressed multiple times even though it was "greyed out". So I'm trying different things, but this made me wonder, *why* doesn't this work?

If the button has `"ng-disabled = true"`, it is disabled. No click, all grey. But if I try `"ng-disabled = {{activeButton}}"` and on .js class write `$scope.activeButton = true;` it doesn't work. I see with the help of F12 that ng-disabled becomes true. But the button is still active, non greyed and clickable.

Why doesn't this work?

As a bonus question, I do have my `$scope.startbuttonActive = on ? "enabled" : "disabled";` that I can work with, which makes the button greyed out but still clickable. What am I missing to disable the button completely?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do not use interpolation markup == {{}}. Instead use ng-disabled="activeButton". Also it has to return a boolean not a string to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller:

```
$scope.buttonClicked = function(){
   $scope.activeButton = !$scope.activeButton;
}
```

in html:

```
 <button ng-click="buttonClicked()" ng-disabled="activeButton">
```

Answer (score 0):

`"ng-disabled = activeButton"`

it gets an "[expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)" which evaluates to boolean.
see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled#!

Comment: That's incorrect syntax it's ng-disabled="myScopeVarThatIndicatesIfToDisable"